# Rails with React only serving React pages when deployed to heroku, can't access any Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, heroku

I'm working with an existing Rails app that has been refactored as an api for React and a dashboard backend. 
A complete React app (with React Router, Redux and Saga) was built and installed into the client folder in the Rails root.

On my local machine, I start a node server on port 3000 and a rails server on 3001. My package.json in the client folder includes
`"proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",`

I can access the React app but it does not get data from the API. I can access the Rails app on 3001. The log error is:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/v1/homedata from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/.
```

My console shows this error:

```
xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/homedata 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

When I deploy to Heroku, the React App is served at my domain but I am unable to access the Rails dashboard. However, the React app properly accesses the Rails API and shows the data.

I have spent about three days searching everywhere for some idea. My best guess at this point is that there is some issue with the Rails server or routes. However I have no idea anymore where to look. I'll post my routes.rb

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
root "dashboard/home#index"
  ### Routing for the dashboard ###
namespace :dashboard do
  resources :home, only: [:index]
  resources :connect_groups
  resources :events
  resources :event_types
  resources :locations
  resources :podcasts
  resources :users
  get "/ajax_load_events", to: "home#ajax_load_events"
  get "/ajax_load_locations", to: "home#ajax_load_locations"
  get "/ajax_load_podcasts", to: "home#ajax_load_podcasts"
  get "/ajax_load_connect_groups", to: "home#ajax_load_connect_groups"
  get "/ajax_load_users", to: "home#ajax_load_users"
  get '', to: 'home#index'
  post "dashboard/podcasts/upload", to: "audio_clips#create"
end

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}

  ### Routing for the new API ###
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :locations
      resources :podcasts
      resources :events
      resources :connect_groups
      resources :messages, only: [ :create]
      get "/location/*id", to: "locations#get_location"
      get "/event/featured", to: "events#featured_events"
      get "/homedata", to: "home#index"
    end
  end


  mount Shrine.presign_endpoint(:cache) => "/presign"

  match "/loaderio-0077704941f2bf1a629295ce9fb1a229", :to => proc { |env| [200, {}, ["loaderio-0077704941f2bf1a629295ce9fb1a229"]] }, via: :get

  get '*path', to: "application#fallback_index_html", constraints: ->(request) do
  !request.xhr? && request.format.html?
end

end
```

Any help or some idea where to start would be a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. It was an issue with not refreshing the browser cache.... duhh